# Problema para almacenar valor SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

tengo un problema para almacenar un valor en mi `BD` en `SQLite`, los demás datos se guardan de manera eficiente pero me falta uno que lo guarda en `Null`. Esta es mi tabla en `SQLite`:

```
//TABLA
public static final String TABLA_SEGUIR = "siguiendo";

//Columnas
public static final String ID_ELEMENTO = "idElementoManga";
public static final String NOMBRE_MANGA = "nombreManga";
public static final String URL_MANGA = "urlManga";
public static final String URL_IMAGEN = "urlImagen";
public static final String CONTADOR_CAPITULOS = "cantidadCapitulos";
public static final String BIT_SEGUIR_NO = "valorSiguiendo";
public static final String TIPO_MANGA = "tipoManga";

public static final String TABLA_PARA_SEGUIR =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLA_SEGUIR + "(" +
                ID_ELEMENTO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                NOMBRE_MANGA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                URL_MANGA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                URL_IMAGEN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                CONTADOR_CAPITULOS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                BIT_SEGUIR_NO + " INTEGER, " +
                TIPO_MANGA + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

Este es mi método para guardar los datos:

```
private ContentValues mapaSiguiendo(SeguirManga sm){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.NOMBRE_MANGA, sm.getNombre());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_MANGA, sm.getUrl());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.URL_IMAGEN, sm.getUrlImagen());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.CONTADOR_CAPITULOS, sm.getContador());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.BIT_SEGUIR_NO, sm.getValorSeguir());
    cv.put(PaginasTabla.TIPO_MANGA, sm.getTipo());
    return cv;
}

public long guardar(SeguirManga sm){
    this.openWriteableDB();
    long filaID = db.insert(PaginasTabla.TABLA_SEGUIR, null, mapaSiguiendo(sm));
    this.closeDB();
    return filaID;
}
```

En mi actividad realizo lo siguiente para almacenar los datos:

```
private void seguirMetodoDato(String urlImagen){
    PaginasSQL psql = new PaginasSQL(TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
    String tipoManga = getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo");
    SeguirManga sm = new SeguirManga();
    sm.setNombre(nombreManga);
    sm.setUrl(url);
    sm.setUrlImagen(urlImagen);
    sm.setContador(cont+"");
    sm.setValorSeguir(1);
    sm.setTipo(tipoManga); //este es el dato que no me almacena
    psql.guardar(sm);
}
```

Ese dato, como verán lo traigo desde otra actividad y pues la verdad es que si llega:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fui hasta mi método para guardar y pues, también llega bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi adaptador trato de mostrarlo pero me lo trae como null:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tmonline_lista_text_view, viewGroup, false);
    }
    TextView nombreManga = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMangaLista);
    ImageView caratula = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivListaMangas);
    SeguirManga sm  = this.seguirMangaArrayList.get(position);
    Picasso.get().load(sm.getUrlImagen()).into(caratula);
    nombreManga.setText(sm.getNombre() + "/" + sm.getTipo());
    return rowView;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen, por algún motivo me lo guarda como null. ¿ALguien sabe por qué?

**ACTUALIZACION:**

```
public class SeguirManga {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private String url;
    private String urlImagen;
    private String contador;
    private int valorSeguir;
    private String tipo;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getContador() {
        return contador;
    }

    public void setContador(String contador) {
        this.contador = contador;
    }

    public int getValorSeguir() {
        return valorSeguir;
    }

    public void setValorSeguir(int valorSeguir) {
        this.valorSeguir = valorSeguir;
    }

    public String getUrlImagen() {
        return urlImagen;
    }

    public void setUrlImagen(String urlImagen) {
        this.urlImagen = urlImagen;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public SeguirManga(){}

    public SeguirManga(int id, String nombre, String url, String urlImagen,String contador, int valorSeguir, String tipo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.url = url;
        this.urlImagen = urlImagen;
        this.contador = contador;
        this.valorSeguir = valorSeguir;
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que obtienes estos valores supuestamente mediante un Intent.

```
private void seguirMetodoDato(String urlImagen){
    ...
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
    String tipoManga = getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo");
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

al realizar la depuraciòn estas visualizando que tiene valor pero al obtener estos valores que provienen de un `Intent` al final van a tener valor null.

**La razòn es que la obtenciòn de estos valores recibidos a partir de un `Intent`, debe realizarse dentro de `onCreate()` de tu `Activity`**:

```
private String url = "";
private String tipoManga = "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
    tipoManga = getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo");
    ...
    ...

}
```

obtenlos y posteriormente asignalos a tu mètodo:

```
private void seguirMetodoDato(String urlImagen){
    PaginasSQL psql = new PaginasSQL(TMOnlineMangaSeleccion.this);
    //String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("valor");
    //String tipoManga = getIntent().getStringExtra("tipo");
    SeguirManga sm = new SeguirManga();
    sm.setNombre(nombreManga);
    sm.setUrl(url);
    sm.setUrlImagen(urlImagen);
    sm.setContador(cont+"");
    sm.setValorSeguir(1);
    sm.setTipo(tipoManga); //este es el dato que no me almacena
    psql.guardar(sm);
}
```

Comment: Pensé que ese podría ser el problema, pero tampoco funcionó. Sigue almacenando el valor en `null`

Comment: Si definiste las variables private String url = "";
private String tipoManga = ""; a nivel de clase, revisa si en onCreate() se reciben valores que no sean null

Comment: Si, se reciben los valores jajaj NO entiendo que estaría mal

Comment: asegura solo definir una variable a nivel de la clase y solo usar esa variable para esto, veo que tienes otro valor que es "url" ese al final no lo usas pero seguramente tiene el mismo problema, si quieres subir tu ejemplo temporalmente a github podría dar un vistazo.

Comment: Mira, la verdad es que incluso en vez de pasar el string desde la otra clase. Directamente lo setié así sm.setTipo("manga"); y tampoco lo almacena ajaja dale, armo un ya te pongo el link del git

Comment: Espera, tal vez el problema es en el objeto SeguirManga !!! , agregalo a tú pregunta. @FranqoBalsamo

Comment: Listo, he añadido la clase SeguirManga

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119324/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-franqo-balsamo).